# Converting datetime to pandas index

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

My pandas dataframe is structured as follows:

```
      date                        tag
0     2015-07-30 19:19:35-04:00   E7RG6
1     2016-01-27 08:20:01-05:00   ER57G
2     2015-11-15 23:32:16-05:00   EQW7G
3     2016-07-12 00:01:11-04:00   ERV7G
4     2016-02-14 00:35:21-05:00   EQW7G
5     2016-03-01 00:08:59-05:00   EQW7G
6     2015-06-19 07:15:06-04:00   ER57G
7     2016-09-08 18:17:53-04:00   ER5TT
8     2016-09-03 01:53:45-04:00   EQW7G
9     2015-11-30 09:31:02-05:00   ER57G
10    2016-03-03 22:28:26-05:00   ES5TG
11    2016-02-11 10:39:24-05:00   E5P7G
12    2015-03-16 07:18:47-04:00   ER57G
...

[11015 rows x 2 columns]
date    datetime64[ns, America/New_York]
tag                               object
dtype: object
```

I'm attempting to set the column 'date' as the index:

```
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']))
```

which yields the following error (using pandas 0.19)

```
File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 3753, in pandas.tslib.tz_localize_to_utc (pandas/tslib.c:64516)
pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from  Timestamp('2015-11-01 01:38:12'), try using the 'ambiguous' argument
```

I've consulted [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html), but I'm still unable to work through this error. For example,

```
    df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']), ambiguous='infer')
```

yields:

```
File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 3703, in pandas.tslib.tz_localize_to_utc (pandas/tslib.c:63553)
pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from 2015-11-01 01:38:12 asthere are no repeated times
```

Any advice on how to convert the datetime column to the index would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: won't `df.set_index(df['date'], inplace=True)` just work?

Comment: Yes! That worked perfectly. Thank you @EdChum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `dtype` for a column is already `datetime` then you can just call `set_index` without the need to try to construct a `DatetimeIndex` from the column:

```
df.set_index(df['date'], inplace=True)
```

should just work, the dtype for the index is sniffed out so there is no need to construct an index object from the Series/column here.

Comment: And in case it's not already a datetime, `df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['date']), inplace=True)` should do the trick :)